# Vim highlighting in textfiles

Tags: highlight

I am a relative new user to vim. I started using it along with a newly set up arch installation.
So when I created different netctl profiles in vim, it highlighted the parameters like shown in the image, without having defined a filetype. But from  one moment, it stopped doing so, the plain text profiles are now unicolored and I cant get it back working, e.g. by switching on syntax highlighting manually.[image: highlighting as it worked out of the box]
Edit: the shown profile is named like in the description, htw_eduroam. No file extension.

Comment: What is an example filename?

Comment: Hey Phil! It looks like you're having some trouble logging into your account. Just so you know, you can use [the contact us](https://vi.stackexchange.com/contact) page to get your two accounts merged

Comment: Most likely, since your file does not have an extension, vim cannot determine what filetype it is. You can try setting the filetype manually. However from your example I cannot tell, what filetype this should be.

Comment: My best bet is that the syntax is python. You can try :set syntax=python.
Another note is that you can see the type of file you are working on easily using the powerline plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Vim generally identifies the filetype(and therefore the syntax higlighting) from the extension of a file. `one.py` would imply that it's a Python file. But in your case, since your file `netctl` does not have an extension, it is not able to ascertain the filetype.

Since the syntax of assignments in `netctl` is very similar to Python, you can type `:set syntax=python` in the normal mode. You could also do the same with `:set filetype=python`. Though it would do the trick, I do not recommend the same.

If you extensively work with these files, you could make your own vim syntax files . Have a look at `:help syntax` in vim.

**Edit : As @Christian mentioned in comment,`:set syntax=dosini` will set the syntax highlighting as it's an `ini` file**

Comment: I would rather try `:set ft=dosini`